# How to run Powershell ScheduledJob (-AtLogOn) in user's session?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Using powershell I'm creating a ScheduledJob to run on user logon (using New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn).

However I noticed that this job runs in session 0 and not in the logged-in user's session.

Also none of the JobTrigger and ScheduledJobOption settings allow me to run in user's session.

Any ideas on how to get this ScheduledJob to run in user's session?

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn
Register-ScheduledJob -Name 'my job' -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock { xxx }
```

Comment: Use a .bat file, and put it in the User's Startup folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-User` parameter:

> -AtLogOn
>
> Starts the scheduled job when the specified users log on to the computer. To specify a user, use the User parameter.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849759.aspx

Comment: Although the `-user` switch causes the task to only run for the specified user, it still runs the task in session 0.

Comment: You must be using old Windows version. Since vista, they run in session of the user. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the only way to do this is to use a ScheduledTask (instead of a ScheduledJob).

Edit: Marking this as an 'answer' since it seemed to resolve my issue. However if someone has a better solution, please feel free to post here.